# Very poor performance from ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've recently imported around 50 000 records into an ActiveAdmin application and am now experiencing very poor performance. Is ActiveAdmin designed to handle this amount of records?

I have got slightly improved performance by adding in `remove_filter` for the filters I am not using.

I don't have any associations, which I know causes some performance issues. My model structure is completely flat with a couple of sub classes using single table inheritance.

I'm using:

```
    ruby '2.1.1'

    gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

    gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

I've got the application deployed to Heroku. I've inserted some logs from Heroku down the bottom.

Here's my model code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Scopes

    scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "status > ?", 100) }
    scope :downward_trending, -> { where( "status < ?", 100) }
    scope :uncategorised, -> {where(category: '') }
    scope :categorised, -> {where.not(category: '') }

end
```

Here's my resource code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
    menu :label => "All Products", :priority => 1

    config.clear_action_items!

        permit_params :name, :link, :category, :image_url, :price, :interest, :interest_changes, :revenue, :start_date, :end_date, :company, :country, :price_eur, :price_gbp, :price_aud, :price_nzd, :price_cad


                # Input

        form do |f|
        f.inputs 'Details' do

            f.input :country, :as => :string
            f.input :category

     end
    f.actions
  end

    # Scopes
    scope :upward_trending, :default => true
    scope :downward_trending
    scope :all

    # Default Sort
    config.sort_order = "end_date_desc"  

    index do
         column "Product Name", :sortable => :name do |a|
            link_to a.name, a.link, :target => "_blank"
        end
        column "Image" do |a|
            div :class => "image_url" do
                link_to (image_tag a.image_url, class: 'image_url'), a.image_url, :target => "_blank", class: 'fancybox'
            end
        end

        column "Price", :sortable => :price_eur do |a|
            div :class => "number" do
                case current_user.currency
                    when 'EUR'
                        number_to_currency(a.price_eur, unit: "€")
                    when 'GBP'
                        number_to_currency(a.price_gbp, unit: "£")
                    when 'AUD'
                        number_to_currency(a.price_aud, unit: "$")
                    when 'CAD'
                        number_to_currency(a.price_cad, unit: "$")
                    when 'NZD'
                        number_to_currency(a.price_nzd, unit: "$")
                    else
                        number_to_currency(a.price, unit: "$")
                    end
                 end
            end

        column "Status", :sortable => :status do |a|
            div :class => "average" do
                number_to_percentage(a.status, precision: 0) 
            end
        end 

        column :category

        column "Updated", :sortable => "end_date"  do |a|
             if a.end_date > Time.now - 5.days
                 distance_of_time_in_words(a.end_date, Time.now, include_seconds: true) + " ago"
             else
                 a.end_date.to_formatted_s(:long)
             end
        end

        #column :company
        #column :country


    end

    # Sidebar

    #sidebar :ProductSearch, :priority => 1 do
    #    render partial: 'admin/search_products', :locals => {:model_name => 'products'}
    #end

    # Filters

    filter :category, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Product.all.collect {|dd| dd.category}.uniq.sort }        
    #filter :name, :label => "Product Name", :as => :string, filters: ['contains']
    #filter :price, :label => "USD Price"
    #filter :interest, :label => "Units Sold"
    #filter :company, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Product.all.collect {|dd| dd.company}.uniq.sort }
    filter :country, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Product.all.collect {|dd| dd.country}.uniq.sort }
    filter :end_date, :label => "Date"
    remove_filter :link
    remove_filter :image_url
    remove_filter :price
    remove_filter :interest
    remove_filter :interest_changes
    remove_filter :revenue
    remove_filter :start_date
    remove_filter :price_eur
    remove_filter :price_gbp
    remove_filter :price_aud
    remove_filter :price_nzd
    remove_filter :price_cad

end
```

Here are some logs from Heroku when loading the resources, in this case it timed out.

```
    2014-09-17T21:22:09.778167+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin/products" for 91.226.23.198 at 2014-09-17 21:22:09 +0000                                                                                                      
2014-09-17T21:22:09.786533+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Admin::ProductsController#index as HTML                                                                                                                             
2014-09-17T21:22:25.828163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29301280.ba6942e6-4473-477d-8fa9-b3de141f9f06 sample#load_avg_1m=0.08 sample#load_avg_5m=0.09 sample#load_avg_15m=0.04                                
2014-09-17T21:22:25.828431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29301280.ba6942e6-4473-477d-8fa9-b3de141f9f06 sample#memory_total=670.15MB sample#memory_rss=511.80MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=15
8.34MB sample#memory_pgpgin=352746pages sample#memory_pgpgout=221723pages                                                                                                                                                      
2014-09-17T21:22:25.829347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=670M(130.9%)                                                                                                                                               
2014-09-17T21:22:25.829678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)                                                                                                                                              
2014-09-17T21:22:39.775186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin/products" host=*.herokuapp.com request_id=e3abc8d7-f52d-47b2-bbb0-161823e1a596 fwd="91.226.23.198" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0                                                                                                                                                                       
2014-09-17T21:22:40.763399+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2014-09-17T21:22:40.714804 #2] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:127 timeout (31s > 30s), killing                                                                                       
2014-09-17T21:22:41.133007+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2014-09-17T21:22:41.132895 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 127 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0                                                                      
2014-09-17T21:22:43.505823+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-17T21:22:43.491614 #158]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready                                                                                                                    
2014-09-17T21:22:46.406853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=9769d818-5231-44db-ab19-d6f7597c308b fwd="91.226.23.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5666ms
 status=304 bytes=111
```

EDIT:

I've tried adding an index on end_date as am sorting descending with this. Unfortunately this made little change on the load times:

```
Sep 17 15:22:34 x app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8556ms (Views: 7377.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1173.7ms) 
Sep 17 15:23:07 x app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8864ms (Views: 7640.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1220.0ms) 
Sep 17 15:28:47 x app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 9551ms (Views: 8039.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1442.5ms) 
Sep 17 15:29:01 x app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8921ms (Views: 7651.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1264.0ms)
```

Comment: You're paginating the results right?

Comment: Hey @PhilipHallstrom thanks for your reply. I believe ActiveAdmin paginates by default, is that correct?

Comment: It does, unless you disabled it somewhere.  Worth double checking...

Comment: Yeah it is paginating to 30 records

Comment: Yep just double checked the initialiser and it is definitely there.

`# == Pagination
  #
  # Pagination is enabled by default for all resources.
  # You can control the default per page count for all resources here.
  #
   config.default_per_page = 30`

Comment: Have you defined index on columns that are used for ordering?  Without the proper indexes the performance could be pretty slow.

Comment: Hey @infused doing this now, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey @infused so I added an index on end_date but no real improvement on load times:

`Sep 17 15:22:34 trendosaur app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8556ms (Views: 7377.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1173.7ms) 
Sep 17 15:23:07 trendosaur app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8864ms (Views: 7640.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1220.0ms) 
Sep 17 15:28:47 trendosaur app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 9551ms (Views: 8039.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1442.5ms) 
Sep 17 15:29:01 trendosaur app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8921ms (Views: 7651.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1264.0ms) `

Comment: It looks like the problem is mostly the view rendering at 7651ms  of the total 8556ms. Hard to tell why. It could be the model's methods you are calling to render some of the data or it could be all the sortables and filters. Try removing some of that stuff until you get decent performance and then put them back one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the culprit was this line of code:

```
filter :country, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Product.all.collect {|dd| dd.country}.uniq.sort }
```

Changed it to:

```
filter :country, :as => :select, :collection => proc { Product.pluck(:country).uniq.sort }
```

Comment: Product.pluck(:country).uniq.sort -> Product.uniq.pluck(:country).sort will make it more faster :)

Comment: Hey @MohitJain this gave me an error:

`PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...T "products"."company" FROM "products"   ORDER BY end_date D...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "products"."company" FROM "products"   ORDER BY end_date DESC`